# how to make a custom TableViewCell that each of them has a different height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm trying to make a tableViewCell that each of them has a different height.I tried declaring each of the cells identifier and it's name and divided into cases by using "switch". And actuallly i also want to indicate a lable on the mainViewCell which is in the code. How can i change each of the cells height?

```
 import UIKit

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewdidload() 
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "mainViewTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "mainViewCell")
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        tableView.scrollEnabled = false
        return 4
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4) {
            case 0:
                let titleCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("titleCell")! as UITableViewCell
            return titleCell
            case 1:
                let wayCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("whichWayCell")! as UITableViewCell
                return wayCell
            case 2:
                let campusCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("campusCell")! as UITableViewCell
                return campusCell
            default :
                    let mainViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mainViewCell")! as! mainViewTableViewCell
                    mainViewCell.mainViewLabel.text = onUpdate(timer)
                    return mainViewCell

        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4) {
    case 0:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1)
    return 50
    case 1:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(2)
    return 50
    case 2:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(3)
    return 50
    default:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4)
    return 300
    }
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
}
```

Comment: what is the issue u r facing ?

Comment: actually i want to indicate a String and change only one cells height but it will inidicate on all cells, to sum up, i want to customize each of the cell by different ways but the customizing will be applied to all cells and that 's that will be the  problem

Comment: what about doing it on storyboard?

Comment: It seemed that the problem has solved. Thank you for your kindness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the indexPath passed into the [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) methods. There are a couple of issues with you code. There is documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

The `switch tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4)` statement in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method should be: `switch(indexPath.section)`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4) {
    case 0:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(1)
    return 50
    case 1:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(2)
    return 50
    case 2:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(3)
    return 50
    default:
        tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(4)
    return 300
}
```

Why are you calling numberOfRowsInSection()?, this should be left to the OS to call. Try this. If you what the tableview cell height to vary due to the section then change `switch(indexPath.row)` to `switch(indexPath.section)`.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height : CGFloat = 0

    switch(indexPath.row) {
    case 0, 2, 3:
        height = 50.0
    case 4:
        height = 300.0
    default:
         break
    }

    return height

}
```

Comment: Sorry i'm still a beginner and it seemed that i wasn't understanding the structure and the words meanings in tableview. But thanks to you, i could solve the problem and know what i have to study, thanks.

Comment: No worries! Keep at it, you will get there ;)